# Tradition-Based Depictions of the Third Temple

Tags: midrash, beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem, art, ezekiel--the-book

Are there any artistic depictions of the third Temple and/or future Jerusalem, available online, that are rooted in traditional descriptions, such as [Ezekiel 40-47](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1240.htm) and related *midrashim*?

Comment: ArtScroll has something I think

Answer (score 2):

This isn't much. Basically showing what the book is about. But is well worth the purchase.

[The Messianic Temple](https://www.chaimclorfene.com/the-messianic-temple/) by Chaim Clorfene.